# Read serial line per line in Processing

Tags: serial-port, processing

I'm working on a simple demo application in [Processing](http://processingjs.org/), this program should eventually show a chart or graph displaying my sensordata.

The problem I'm having is that I can't find any other method to read from the Serial port other then using `port.readString()`. This seems like the right way to do so, but this way it doesn't read the serial per line.

This is the current output I am getting, don't worry about the 'Writing to file' and 'Items written:' text. I know how to fix this and it's not a problem.

[image]

For the input of the program each line should consist of 12 values. Without having this it will get much harder to get a graph out of this data.

Is there any way to get the Serial data per line instead of 'random' linebreaks in the middle of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Serial library documentation](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/index.html), it sounds like you're looking for [the `readStringUntil()` function](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_readStringUntil_.html).

The `readStringUntil()` function does exactly like you described and reads a `String` until it gets to a character you specify, which can be a line break. In fact that's what the example in that link uses.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you could use the `bufferUntil()` function and the `serialEvent()` callback to get events whenever a line is completed. Or you could simply detect the line break yourself and split the values as appropriate.

I'd recommend trying something and posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Wow, you're right. This seems like the perfect solution. I don't get it how this didn't come up at my search results before.
Ill check tomorrow if this works good for me :D

Comment: @MathieuBrouwers No problem. Hope it works for you. Full disclosure: I've never actually used the Serial library before, so this was my best guess from reading the documentation. If there's a better answer, I'm sure George (the other Processing guy around here) will be around soon. :p

Comment: The only thing which doesn't really make sense to me now is the following. 
The `readStringUntil()` method takes an int as argument, I can't say `readStringUntil("\n")`, but having `10` as int in there does what it should be doing as said on the documentation from the serial library.

Thanks!

Comment: @MathieuBrouwers It takes an `int`, but really it's a character. Ascii represents the `\n` character as the `int` value `10`. More info here: http://www.asciitable.com/